# get recordingSid in Twilio Studio Flow

Tags: twilio

I've created a flow in Twilio Studio, which I access via the Studio REST API. This flow makes a phone call and serves as a simple IVR. I would like to provide access to the recording of this call to my end users.

I would like to get the recordingSid returned to my application.

Is this possible? I see references to RecordingStatusCallback being passed as a parameter to the non-Studio REST API, but it appears that there is no support for this in the Studio REST API.

I think I can grab the CallSid from widget data and then show the list of recordings for that Call, but this isn't a seamless as being able to provide my users with a direct link to the recording.

Happy for any guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you want the recordingSid returned to your application, where do you want this to happen? How does your Studio Flow get triggered and how is the recording made?

Comment: The Studio Flow is triggered by my application via the REST API, and the recording is enabled by a configuration property on the "Make Outgoing Call" widget that makes the call to my end users. I'd be happy to get the recordingSid anywhere.

Comment: I'm just coming up with ideas at the moment, as I can't think of a solid solution, but once the call completes could point it at a function that gets the `CallSid` as part of the incoming request parameters and then send that somewhere, or use it to get the recording SIDs at that point (even though the recordings may not be ready)?

Comment: That's kinda the approach I'm taking - on complete, call a webhook that sends the `CallSid` back to my application, at which point I can put together a URL, GET it, and parse the response for the recording. It would be great if that `RecordingStatusCallback` feature was available in Studio, but I get that Studio is in beta and hope that feature gets added. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've mentioned this to the Studio team. Hopefully something will be added for you.